# How can I create a static array field that is accessible, but not mutable?

Tags: java

In "Effective Java" (2nd edition), on page 70, it states:

> Note that a non-zero length array is always mutable, so it is wrong
>   for a class to have a public static final array field, or an accessor
>   that returns such a field. If a class has such a field or accessor,
>   clients will be able to modify the contents of the array. This is a
>   frequent source of security holes:
>
> ```
> // Potential security hole!
> public static final Thing[] VALUES = { ... }
> ```

The book then proposes the following as a solution:

```
private static final Thing[] PRIVATE_VALUES = { ... };
public static final Thing[] values() {
    return PRIVATE_VALUES.clone();
}
```

However, I don't see how this solves the problem.

Consider the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Thing {
    public int yolo = 4;
}

class Test {
    private static final Thing[] VALUES = { new Thing(), new Thing() };
    public static final Thing[] values() {
        return VALUES.clone();
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test.values()[0].yolo = 5;
        System.out.println(Test.values()[0].yolo);
    }
}
```

The above code prints "5" as output. Am I missing something or is this an error in the book?

Comment: You're not mutating the array, you're mutating an element in the array. That's an entirely separate issue.

Comment: You would need a "deep clone" for what you are trying to prevent.

Comment: @luk2302 or better, make Thing an immutable class, and expose an unmodifiable List rather than an array.

Comment: @shmosel How come "public static final Thing[] VALUES = {...}" is a security hole then?

Comment: Because "clients will be able to modify the contents of the array".

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, nice one. The author also suggests a solution similar to that.

Comment: @shmosel Oh, I see. So, for that matter, "final" on any object is not very effective if that Object's fields are modifiable. It's only really effective on primitives.

Comment: It's effective for any immutable type, including primitives. It also has its uses for mutable types, but you shouldn't assume a field is fully immutable because it has the `final` modifier.

Comment: @shmosel Ah, so a good way to think of it is that "final" prevents reassignment, not that it freezes the object or somehow makes it immutable. Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not mutating the original array `VALUES`.

When you call `Test.values()`, it returns a *clone* of the `VALUES` array and not the original array itself. You modified the clone array and thus got the output as 5; the original array didn't get modified.